# What is the most suitable classification algorithm to classify legal document pictures?

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence

I have a set of documents such as (identifiers, driving license and passports etc) in more than one country, so i need to classify them each in its class and then i can classify any new documents -not in my set- in its class.

Documents maybe rotated or shifted or both .
Documents color of two documents from the same class maybe not exactly the same .

What is the best algorithm to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it's not a true classification problem.  Additionally, because you have items that might be rotated, skewed, etc, you should really perform some sort of object detection/feature analysis on the images.

I'd recommend looking into [perceptual hashing](http://phash.org/) or [Speeded Up Robust Features (SURF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF) (more the latter, if you are dealing with a tremendous amount of rotation/skew).  Namely, I'd break the images down into regions that are non-identifying (you would eliminate areas that have the user's information, or their photo, for example) concentrating on areas that have a high number of matching feature points.

Use areas that are consistent across all instances of a particular class of ID so that your match scores will be higher, then take aggregates of all the sections you compare to perform your classification.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is not which classification algorithm to choose, but to understand all the relevant hidden dimensions in your classification problem. Once you understand all the dimensions involved, you could use any one of the classification algorithms to achieve what you want.

Comment: You are right, but what are the main dimensions in your opinion? i thought in the histogram, texture, size, and some other features. What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately, the main dimensions are a function of the problem space. I will start with an exhaustive set of dimensions (all that I could think ..) and train it using some supervised algorithms.  Then I will introduce stochastic variations in the input data and measure the performance difference.

Comment: I suggest Image Processing Cookbook. It is a very good beginners guide. http://www.amazon.com/Image-Processing-Cookbook-processing-scientific/dp/1448691214

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens if not hundreds of classification algorithms -- basically what you are looking for is clustering.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

To make this work, you are going to have to analyze the document and boil it down to a few key numbers.  This doesn't have to be perfect for clustering to work.

So, it might be good to do some kind of normalization (rotate all documents so that text is horizontal), but perhaps not.  For example, if a key classification number was based on overall color -- that would be the same for any rotation.

Comment: But the classes are known, clustering is used to determine the classes, as i know!

Comment: What are the main features or key numbers should i gather from the documents in your opinion?

Comment: It's similar with known classes: just measure the distance between known and unknown.  The key is still coming up with the parameters to calculate distance with.  It's very domain specific, so it's hard to give suggestions.  If you can't rotate, you need to choose things that are the same regardless of rotation.  Much better if you can rotate --  OCR (e.g. Tesseract) can help you do that (try all four rotations 0, 90, 180, 270) -- which ever gives you the most real words is the probable one.  You might be able to narrow it down if you know the ratio of height to width (check for upside-down).